# Mails are going to spam is it because of Heartbeat not found?

Tags: magento-1.9, email, cron

we are getting below error through AOE scheduler extension

```
Last heartbeat is older than one hour. Please check your settings and your configuration!
```

& order , password reset and other  Mails are going to **spam**.

Is there any link b/w spam & heartbeat ?

because catalog price rules are working fine.

**cron.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006-2015 X.commerce, Inc. (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

// Change current directory to the directory of current script
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));

require 'app/bootstrap.php';
require 'app/Mage.php';

if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
    echo "Application is not installed yet, please complete install wizard first.";
    exit;
}

// Only for urls
// Don't remove this
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);

Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);

umask(0);

$disabledFuncs = explode(',', ini_get('disable_functions'));
$isShellDisabled = is_array($disabledFuncs) ? in_array('shell_exec', $disabledFuncs) : true;
$isShellDisabled = (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) ? $isShellDisabled : true;
$isShellDisabled = true;

try {
    if (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) {
        $options = getopt('m::');
        if (isset($options['m'])) {
            if ($options['m'] == 'always') {
                $cronMode = 'always';
            } elseif ($options['m'] == 'default') {
                $cronMode = 'default';
            } else {
                Mage::throwException('Unrecognized cron mode was defined');
            }
        } else if (!$isShellDisabled) {
            $fileName = basename(__FILE__);
            $baseDir = dirname(__FILE__);
            shell_exec("/bin/sh $baseDir/cron.sh $fileName -mdefault 1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
            shell_exec("/bin/sh $baseDir/cron.sh $fileName -malways 1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
            exit;
        }
    }

    Mage::getConfig()->init()->loadEventObservers('crontab');
    Mage::app()->addEventArea('crontab');
    if ($isShellDisabled) {
        Mage::dispatchEvent('always');
        Mage::dispatchEvent('default');
    } else {
        Mage::dispatchEvent($cronMode);
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::printException($e);
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: You cron is not set properly, please set corn.php with every 5 min using cpanel and check

Comment: @User34444 we followed this : `*/5 * * * * /bin/sh /[magento_path]/cron.sh */5 * * * * /bin/bash /[magento_path]/cron.sh */5 * * ` as in [link](http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/395-setting-up-cron-jobs-in-magento) , it worked in one server , but didt worked in another server. so ithought its magento problem.

Comment: Some time commend not working in cpanel, please let me know your cpanel name

Comment: @User34444 sorry, i forget to info before only, we are not using cpanel, we are using VPS

Comment: @User34444 we used this :   `*/5 * * * * php -f /var/www/html/sitename/cron.php`

Comment: Yes it seems ok, can you please check open your cron.php file and

replace
$disabledFuncs = explode(',', ini_get('disable_functions'));
$isShellDisabled = is_array($disabledFuncs) ? in_array('shell_exec', $disabledFuncs) : true;
$isShellDisabled = (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) ? $isShellDisabled : true;

with this

$disabledFuncs = explode(',', ini_get('disable_functions'));
$isShellDisabled = is_array($disabledFuncs) ? in_array('shell_exec', $disabledFuncs) : true;
$isShellDisabled = (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) ? $isShellDisabled : true;
$isShellDisabled : true;

Comment: @User34444 please check updated question with cron.php code

Comment: Yes, now please check

Comment: still going to spam, i checked with `password reset mail`

Comment: First Please let me know cron is working or not?

Comment: @User34444 catlog price rules are working, so i guess cron is working, can you please tell how to check

Comment: Go to system >> Scheduler >> Schedule Configuration and check message here

Comment: @User34444 still this error : `Last heartbeat is older than one hour. Please check your settings and your configuration!`

Comment: Still Your cron is not set properly.

reason for Spam mail:
-subject
-content
-bad reputation
-spelling mistake

Comment: may i check mail is going to inbox or spam by installing [smtp pro](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html) extension ?

Comment: @User34444 we found this error : ` -bash : */5 : no such file or directory.`  when i ran this command : `*/5 * * * * php -f /var/www/html/totaltoys/cron.php`

Comment: IF cron is set properly it show like this https://snag.gy/jlZ40D.jpg

Comment: @User34444 yes befroe it was working properly as in the scrrenshot , dont know what wrong happened suddenly.

Comment: Please check this also may help you
http://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39859/discussion-on-question-by-baby-in-magento-mails-are-going-to-spam-is-it-because).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if it is related to AOE Scheduler or not, but once I got the same issue that is all the emails are going into the spam. 
To fix the issue I have set the `Set Return-Path` to `Yes` under `System -> Configuration -> System -> Mail Sending Settings`

Check http://inchoo.net/magento/fight-spam-emails/ as well.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge, unfortunately it didt worked for me.

Comment: @BabyinMagento : Check article http://inchoo.net/magento/fight-spam-emails/ , may be this will help you out.